# Test coverage for JSON.derserializeuntyped Method

Tags: unit-test

I have the following response for my callout from apex trigger to an external webservice.

JSON Response:

```
{"status":"ok","data":{"account_id":"6819"}}
```

Apex class method for parsing the JSON using JSON.deserializeUntyped:

```
  Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    system.debug(m);
    if(m.get('status') == 'ok' || m.get('status') == 'error' ){
    map<string,object> data = (map<string,object>)m.get('data');
    system.debug('---data----'+data);
    if(m.get('status') == 'ok'){
     opp.Account_Id__c=String.ValueOf(data.get('account_id'));
     }
    else if(m.get('status') == 'error'){
    opp.Sync__c=String.valueOf(data.get('message'));
    }
    SUPPRESS_OPP_UPDATE_CALLOUT = true;
    update opp;
    }
```

I was not able to cover the above lines in my test class of updating my opp fields with the response.

Comment: The JSON logic looks OK. But if the `Account_Id__c` field is a lookup field the assignment of the value '6819' will cause an "Invalid ID" exception and so stop the processing at that point.

Comment: @Keith: Its not a lookup field just a regular Number filed but though I try to do opp.Account_Is__c='1234' I dont see any coverage on these lines

Comment: Then `opp.Account_Id_c = Decimal.valueOf((String) data.get('account_id'));` might make more sense. Add more debug output until you track the problem down.

Comment: Thanks @Keith C, I figured it out using the debug logs increased the code coverage to 91%.